# Using ssh via C code

Tags: c, linux, ssh, terminal

I tried to connect to ssh using following code in C

```
  system("ssh DestinationPC")
```

It works now it wants password from me. What is the easiest way to send it and how can I send some terminal commands using C?

Any kind of good answers or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you try to do this? Please edit your question to explain more the actual use case.

Comment: Please explain more why you want to do that, and what exactly are the remote commands you intend to run. **It smells very bad.**

Comment: I will downvote the question, because you don't explain the context and why you want to do that. There might be other better ways to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to setup your `ssh` appropriately, e.g. using public keys, to avoid any password been asked. Any good [ssh tutorial](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux) explains that.

<sup>(don't even think of sending the password programatically; it is possible, but is very unsecure and ugly)</sup>

Then you either need to give a command to run by `ssh`  e.g.

```
 int err = system("ssh DestinationPC rm /tmp/badfile.txt")
```

or you could use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to send several commands (you need to redirect the output):

```
 FILE* remf = popen("ssh DestinationPC > remoteoutput.txt", "w");
 if (!remf) { perror("popen ssh failed"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 fprintf(remf, "gcc somesource.c -Wall -o somebinary\n");
 fprintf(remf, "./somebinary");
 fclose(remf);
```

but this might be insecure.

Be sure to understand what [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) means and to carefully try to avoid it.

You probably will construct your command string (e.g. using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html). Be careful (buffer overflow, truncation, code injection, argument quoting...). Check every input-related data going into that command string.

You might be interested in [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL).

You might also use two [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s (one for input, one for output from the `fork`-ed `ssh` process) then you'll need some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) probably around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

In general, be very careful about security issues.

Unless you know well what you are doing, coding `system("ssh DestinationPC`...`")`  is often a **bad idea** (and a recipe for disasters). At least document when and how your software is doing that. Look also into [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface)

### addenda

<sup>(added in september 2016)</sup>

You might be interested in [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/) instead of executing some `ssh` command with `system` or `popen`...

Comment: Regarging the use of `popen()` it might be worth mentioning that the ssh-client's output cannot be read if the call is to `popen()` was done to write to the ssh-client.

Comment: This is why I was redirecting to `remoteoutput.txt`

Comment: Oh yes, nice. I overlooked this, sorry.